# DynamoDB put request for a particular field

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am doing some tests on my DynamoDB,

I have done put request by CLI as follow:

`aws dynamodb put-item --table-name sensor_data --item "{\"node_id\":{\"S\":\"1234\"},\"timestamp\":{\"N\":\"223456789\"},\"val\":{\"N\":\"1\"}}`"

the table is like below:

```
node_id   timestamp  val
1234      223456789  1
```

now if I do

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name sensor_data --item "{\"node_id\":{\"S\":\"1234\"},\"timestamp\":{\"N\":\"223456789\"}}
```

The data for val column become earased

```
node_id   timestamp
1234      223456789
```

I am looking for something like Hbase put which just update the relevant fields in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I shoud use updateitem:

```
aws dynamodb update-item --table-name sensor_data --key "{\"node_id\":{\"S\":\"1234\"},\"timestamp\":{\"N\":\"223456789\"}}" --update-expression "SET #Y = :y" --expression-attribute-names "{\"#Y\":\"value\"}" --expression-attribute-values "{\":y\": {\"N\":\"0.0\"}}"
```